# Does "at least either .. or .." make sense?

Tags: conjunctions

> 1. Either she or he should attend that meeting.
> 2. **At least** either she or he should attend that meeting.

I created the two sentences above. According to my understanding, the first sentence eliminates the possibility that both she and he will attend that meeting. I created the second sentence to include that possibility, but I am not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Is “or” exclusive?

From your first example

- “Does `A or B` mean one **but not** both?”

This is a question which has raised some debates both here on *ELL* and *English Language & Usage* Stack Exchange.

The short answer is “it usually means just one, but sometimes it can mean both are allowed.” It depends on the context.

The ***default*** reading you are using is correct, just one of them needs to attend.  (But perhaps both of them will— it depends.) See [here for more](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95624/use-of-or-inclusive-or-exclusive) on this topic at EL&U.

Note: because “or” can be ambiguous in this way, in the study of logic, and in several programming languages, the term “XOR” is used for “exclusive or” — one but not both.

## Your alternative

Your sentence is a very brave attempt at solving a hard problem:

> At least either she or he should attend

Unfortunately, *at least either* does not work very well and sounds awkward.

The sentence could be rephrased this way:

> ✔️**Yes:** At least one of them should attend.
>
> ✔️**Yes:** At least one of them, but not both, should attend.
>
> ✔️**Yes:** Between Alice and Bob, at least one of them should attend.
>
> ✔️**Yes:** Between the two of them, at least one <s>(of them)</s> should attend.
>
> ✔️ **Yes:** Alice or Bob, or both of them, should attend.

**The last one is the simplest and best.**  Notice that it uses “*them*”,  but it also establishes who “*them*” is (who “they” are).

If you can’t use “them”, I would use their names instead of “she and he” because this still sounds awkward:

> **Acceptable but awkward:** Between she and he, at least one should attend.

Comment: You left out one possibility: *Alice or Bob, or both of them, should attend.* That matches the intended meaning of the second sentence in the question. In fact, it almost seems to me that was what the question was actually asking.

Comment: @JasonBassford +1 very good suggestion. Answer updated!